# What happens when you write(byte[] b) to a BufferedOutputStream? (Java)

Tags: java, bufferedoutputstream

When you use the method write(byte[] b) to write to a BufferedOutputStream, the write method from FilterOutputStream is used. The documentation says:

"The write method of FilterOutputStream calls its write method of three arguments with the arguments b, 0, and b.length. "

Which write method with three arguments is it referring to? The one in FilterOutputStream, or the one in BufferedOutputStream? (i.e. is the write actually buffered?).

I believe it is, but I'm not sure.

Comment: *Its* write method. Its own. This is perfectly clear. Downvoting.

Comment: It is not "perfectly clear" as it does not have one. :) But yes, in the end it will end up in the overwritten method of BufferedOutputStream (easy to check with eclipse, just ctrl+click on the methods twice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferedOutputStream` *overrides* the `write(byte[], int, int)` method, so that new override is called.  Yes, the write is buffered.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is both yes and no. To summarize my finds: the effective result is a little different than what the promise ("buffered") because whether the stream is flushed immediately depends both on the size of the buffer and in the amount of data you store per call.

The following is from the somewhat more detailed http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html (emphasis my own):

> Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off **to this buffered output stream**.
>
> Ordinarily this method stores bytes from the given array into this stream's buffer, **flushing the buffer to the underlying output stream as needed**. If the requested length is at least as large as this stream's buffer, however, then this method **will flush the buffer and write the bytes directly to the underlying output stream**. Thus redundant BufferedOutputStreams will not copy data unnecessarily.

Comment: It's as buffered as `BufferedOutputStream` ever gets, no?

Comment: Indeed. Just saying that the effect of having a flush after each call is tha same or worse than having the stream be unbuffered. It all depends on whether OP chooses the buffersize appropriate in relation to the amount of data he stores on each call.

Comment: I'm aware of the subtleties of the write(byte[], int, int) method as you explain eznme. Thanks anyway though. As Louis says, when I said 'buffered', I meant 'buffered' in the sense of 'a buffer is involved'

Comment: There is another nuance. If the written bytes do not fit into the half-full buffer (you write 400 bytes into a 500 byte buffer which is 128 bytes filled) then it will flush the 128 bytes and afterwards start with a buffer filled with a copy of the 400 bytes. This effectively can lead to very small writes, it does not max out the buffer.